# CSS / Media queries

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

I have used Mailchimp's 1-column template to create an email invite.

However, when I export the HTML out, render it with Mailchimp's CSS inliner tool and send a test blast to my email.

It looks okay on Outlook, but it does not display correctly on Gmail App. I understand that on Gmail App, it does not support media queries.

May I know what other ways can i make my template be mobile-friendly other than tweaking the media queries?

Comment: Can you show us an example of "not displaying correctly on Gmail" and "looks okay on Outlook'?

Comment: Include some images and some of the relevant code.

Comment: @Mave I am unable to attached a screenshot of how it looks like...

Comment: @AshleyMedway I am unable to attached a screenshot of how it looks like...

Answer (score 0):

Use percentage measurements for your layout components. That way you can build a website that works on a much larger range of screen sizes. You can combine this approach with media queries - for example, you could specify that your site has a 25% wide navigation menu and a 75% wide content area on devices that are wider than 400px, but any smaller than that and it collapses to a single column layout with the menu hidden and accessible only through a menu bar icon.